# hosts file and unblocked subdomains

Tags: windows-7, blocking, hosts

I modified hosts file to block google.com and its subdomains but it blocks only the main domain name. It does not block the subdomains.
Windows 7 Starter

127.0.0.1 google.com

It blocks google.com but dows not block www.google.com

Then I tried this one:
127.0.0.1 *google.com
It didn't helped.

Comment: Why would you want to block Google?

Comment: It is just an example domain. I do not want to show the real domain here.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm guessing it was before the migration, but just in case, it's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Maybe edit this to read example.com to stop the freak-out comments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hosts file is very basic, and by basic i mean BASIC. 
You are going to have to do

```
127.0.0.1 google.com
127.0.0.1 www.google.com
127.0.0.1 wave.google.com
127.0.0.1 docs.google.com
```

etc

If you are trying to pull a prank, use that, if you want to get serious, you need to invest in a network firewall or some such that will allow you to block domain names.

Comment: And google doubleclick.net knows how to get around that by spamming the subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

The hosts file doesn't support wildcards. You will need an ad blocking proxy / DNS program to do that. See e.g. [TreeWalk DNS](http://ntcanuck.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think your hosts file may be being rolled back by the built-in Windows Defender.

Deactivate Defender then edit the hosts file, making sure to remove any read-only attribute.

Comment: windows defender is a windows 8 thing. This question predates it by about 3 years.